# How we can find the Xpath of loader image in webapplication

Tags: selenium, xpath

in some web application when we click some radio button the page is getting loaded at that time some loader icon is getting displayed . the issue is that the loader image is appearing only for few seconds and getting disappeared. How we can find the xpath for the loader image

Comment: In most of the application, the loader images are loading when page loads and it is hidden status. if you go thru dom elements, then you find it. otherwise ask developer.

Comment: Thanks Murthi . I'll check with the developer

Answer (score 0):

If your page is slower this will give you more time to look for the XPath. You can try to [throttle the network](https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/) (make your browser temporarily slower). This could be done from Chrome DevTools. For Windows:

1. Press F12 to open Devtools.
2. Click "More tools" (three dots menu).
3. Click "Network conditions".
4. Select network throttling profile.